# Get points on a zoomed view on MS Chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, zooming

I'm using Microsoft Chart controls and allowing user selection.
I want to be able to get the data points of the current zoomed (viewed) area once the user selects an area to zoom. Any ideas on how can this be done? I'm using .Net 4.5.

Comment: Did you hvae a go with the updated version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that sends the currently visible `DataPoints` to the Console output:

```
// two shortcuts
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S = chart1.Series[0];

// these are the X-Values of the zoomed portion:
double min = CA.AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
double max = CA.AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

// these are the respective DataPoints:
    DataPoint pt0 = S.Points.Select(x => x)
                     .Where(x => x.XValue >= min)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(S.Points.First()).First();
    DataPoint pt1 = S.Points.Select(x => x)
                     .Where(x => x.XValue <= max)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(S.Points.Last()).Last();

// test output:
for (int i = S.Points.IndexOf(pt0); i < S.Points.IndexOf(pt1); i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i + " :  " + S.Points[i]);
```

You can put this in the `SelectionRangeChanged` event.

Comment: The idea behind it is good although I dont believe this code will work unless there will be actual points on the maximum and minimum values of the view, which is very unlikely. I will just try and filter the data to get all the points between Min and Max in a similar manner as you did

Comment: You're right, I have modified the answer a little. Please try to see if it works for your data as well, now..!