# Find Max and Min values on the interval in ChartArea c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

I have a **Chart**. There is a **ChartArea**, I need to find Max and Min values on a **Chart**. How can I do it?

P.S. There is a **Series** and AxisX has time [not numbers, see a screenshot].

My problem is i can't get PointIndex [sure, I can do it, but when I don't click to DataPoint, but I click to just ChartArea that I can't get PointIndex, because is was **-1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Series s` you can find the minimum and maximum **values** like this:

```
double minX = s.Points.Select(v => v.XValue).Min();
double maxX = s.Points.Select(v => v.XValue).Max();
double minY = s.Points.Select(v => v.YValues[0]).Min();
double maxY = s.Points.Select(v => v.YValues[0]).Max();
```

Note that they do not directly map into the `Points` as **each** value may occur **multiple** times. So to find the **first** and **last** matching `DataPoint` we can use this:

```
// find datapoints from left..
DataPoint minXpt = s.Points.Select(p => p)
                    .Where(p => p.XValue == minX)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(s.Points.First()).First();
DataPoint minYpt = s.Points.Select(p => p)
                    .Where(p => p.YValues[0] == minY)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(s.Points.First()).First();
//..or from right
DataPoint maxXpt = s.Points.Select(p => p)
                    .Where(p => p.XValue == maxX)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(s.Points.Last()).Last();
DataPoint maxYpt = s.Points.Select(p => p)
                    .Where(p => p.YValues[0] == maxY)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(s.Points.Last()).Last();
```

Now after marking the found points, maybe like this:

```
Color c = Color.Green;

minXpt.MarkerColor = c;
minYpt.MarkerColor = c;
maxXpt.MarkerColor = c;
maxYpt.MarkerColor = c;

minXpt.MarkerSize = 12;
minYpt.MarkerSize = 12;
maxXpt.MarkerSize = 12;
maxYpt.MarkerSize = 12;
```

I get this result:

[image]

See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141897/calculation-from-zoomable-graph-c-sharp/30144626?s=3|0.0598#30144626) how to restrict the search to a **zoomed interval**!

Comment: maybe you didn't understand what i wanted or i didn't ask as good as possible. `double minX = s.Points.Select(v => v.XValue).Min();` you wrote. But it founds only min of **FULL** series. And when i pick out my interval that my min value doesn't change.

Comment: Actually i can say what i need. When i pick my interval then i get **first point X** and **second point X**, then i use `zoom(first, second)`. And i need one feature. When i pick out my interval, then i need to finds **max Y** and **min Y** on the interval and after i need to set `AxisY.Maximum = maxY`. This is my task, but i can't understand how i can do it. I hope you can understand my English :)

Comment: Did you notice the link at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I saw it, i even tried it. But id didn't work with my ChartArea. I'm sure it was my mistake :) Your code was working, i think. But i did my problem else. Thank you for answer.