# Get the X axis value of the maximum point in ChartArea C#

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart

I'd like to get the x axis value of the maximum point from the chart bellow. [image]

You can see that the value I get is around 67, even though it should be around 30. I thought it happened because of I also limit the chart maximum X axis into a certain value with the `chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum` code, then I tried the following code to get the maximum value `var dataPoint = chart3.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue();`. So maybe this code is searching the maximum value from the whole series, not only from the visible chart area.

My question is, is there any idea to get the maximum value from the visible chart area only?? Or maybe it's better to erase the unwanted chart series, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking out this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822227/get-points-on-a-zoomed-view-on-ms-chart).

The below code will search all `DataPoint` in the `Series`.

```
var xAxisValue = chart3.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue();
```

So, from the link above you can get the value you require by doing something like this:

```
var scaleView = chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView;
var min = scaleView.ViewMinimum;
var max = scaleView.ViewMaximum;

var yourAnswerMaybe = chart3.Series[0].Points
            .Where(p => p.XValue > min && p.XValue < max)
            .OrderBy(p => p.XValue)
            .Last()
            .XValue;
```

Comment: I've tried to understand your idea, then tried it in exactly the same way with yours. But then I realized it only get the last visible axis value. 

Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. Actually I want to get the x Axis position of the maximum point. In this case I should get the "32" something result. 

In my first trial, I got 67.72, because if I extend the chart, you will see that I have another maximum peak in 67.72 freq, even though I want to get the 32 freq result.

Comment: I have tried to change `Last()` to `Max()`, but then I got this error "at least one object must implement Icomparable"